# Is it possible to add a class and a style to a Razor element

Tags: css, model-view-controller, razor

Is it possbile to add a style AND a class atrribute to a Razor element.

```
 <div style="width:170px;float:left;">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPremise, Model.PremiseList, "Please select", new { @class = "selectpicker", data_style="btn-primary" ,style="width:100px;"})
  </div>
```

This does not work...

Comment: try below code which i have given for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add.

find below example for reference.

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "class-name" }, { "style", "display:none" } });
```

Comment: hi, it did work but it did not like this: { "data-style", "btn-primary" },

Comment: hi Andrew, can i get your mail address. i had seen you are pretty good in windows phone development. i will send questions if i had any, since i have recently started windows mobile app development in my company

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72521/discussion-between-pavan-uideveloepr-and-andrew-simpson).